# Add separation between atoms and charges in Chemfig

Tags: chemfig

I am drawing Lewis diagrams and need a little more space between the atoms, electrons, and charges.  I cannot find anything that adds more separation between the atoms and \charge.  Anyone know how I can do this?

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\begin{document}
\noindent
\chemfig{\charge{90=\:,180=\:,270=\:}{A}-\charge{90=\:,0=\:,270=\:}{B}^{-1}}
\end{document}
```

Comment: In chemistry, the "+" or "-" sign in ions is placed after the number, e.g. 2+, 3-, etc, and not +2, -3, which are exponents used in mathematics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\begin{document}
\setcharge{extra sep = 4pt}
\chemfig{\charge{90=\:,180=\:,270=\:}{A}-\charge{90=\:,0=\:,270=\:, 25:6pt=$-1$}{B}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

you can use the \charge command for this, adding as much space as you like,placing the sign in the position you want.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\begin{document}
    \noindent
    \chemfig{\charge{90=\:,180=\:,270=\:}{A}-\charge{90=\:,0=\:,270=\:,30:5pt=$-$}{B}}
\end{document}
```

[image]